# $scope binding to array of null values AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I am new to AngularJs and have trouble going around how to bind $scope in my controller to a 2-d json array which has some fields which has null values, because whenever i try to bind it console throws an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of null"

here is what i am trying to accomplish:

```
 $scope.posts = [
    {title: 'post1', upvotes: null},
    {title: null, upvotes: 4},
    {title: null,    upvotes: 8},
    {title: 'post4', upvotes: null},
    {title: 'post5', upvotes: 5}
];
```

but here's the twist if I give value of upvotes of 'post4' say 8 then console gives no error though there are still some fields with null values.

Can anyone tell me where's the bug and how to bind $scope with array with some fields having null values like above.

thanks

EDIT

Got the solution in my template i was using orderBy filter on negative of upvotes which had null values so that's why it was throwing error.

Comment: What do you mean 'bind $scope with null values'? Could you post an example of what you are trying to do? Simply defining an array like you have done is perfectly valid...

Comment: i have a controller myApp.controller and in that i am binding a variable 'posts' to $scope using a dot operator and in my view using ng-repeat to display their title and upvotes but when i check my console this error is coming as i passed some null values..

Comment: For example if I make 'upvotes' field of every row null then this error comes else it might not come, i mean it is not definitive as to when this error comes, on what parameters etc. It's uncertain that's why posted question here

Comment: you would better post the html and js including your controller/directive as well

Comment: Can you post an example? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/6u1c7e3j/) example based on what you posted works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, Got the solution in my template i was using orderBy filter on negative of upvotes which had null values so that's why it was throwing error.

Comment: Why don't you add answer to this question rather than editing the question. It's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, in my template i was using 'orderBy' filter on negative of upvotes which had null values so it was unable to order by null values. I removed that filter and there was no error in console.